# Eigen Values of $(\frac{1}{3x^2+1}y’)’+\lambda (3x^2+1)y=0, y(0)=0, y(\pi)=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

How to find eigen values of Sturm Liouville Problem $$(\frac{1}{3x^2+1}y’)’+\lambda (3x^2+1)y=0, y(0)=0, y(\pi)=0?$$ I only know how to find eigen values of $y’’+\lambda y=0, y(0)=y(\pi)=0,$ because ODE $y’’+\lambda y=$ can be solve easily . I have no ideal how to find eigen values of $$(\frac{1}{3x^2+1}y’)’+\lambda (3x^2+1)y=0, y(0)=0, y(\pi)=0.$$ please help. Thank you.

Comment: You should finally get the eigenvalues 
$$\lambda=\frac{(2 n)^2}{\left(1+\pi ^2\right)^2}, n\in \mathbb{Z}\land n>0$$
or
$$\lambda=\frac{(1+2 n)^2}{\left(1+\pi ^2\right)^2}, n\in \mathbb{Z}\land n\ge 0$$

Comment: @gpmath yes now I got the answer.  Can you see this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733746/sturm-liouville-probelm-x21y-frac-lambda-x21y-0-y0-y1-0?noredirect=1#comment10035510_4733746 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $y(x)=z(\xi)$, where $\xi=x^3+x$. Show that $z(\xi)$ satisfies the ODE $z''(\xi)+\lambda z(\xi)=0$ with boundary conditions $z(0)=z(\pi^3+\pi)=0.$

Comment: and what about boundary conditions?

Comment: $y(0)=0$ still holds but what about second boundary condition.

Comment: This is a dangerous double-use of the letter $y$. Better define $y(x)=z(\xi)$, visually separating the two different functions.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann can you explain in answer in details. Thank you sir .

Comment: @LutzLehmann how boundary conditions changed?

Comment: $x=\pi$ corresponds to $\xi=\pi^3+\pi$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thank you very much .