# Sturm-Liouville Problem $((x^2+1)y’)’+\frac{\lambda }{x^2+1}y=0, y(0)=y(1)=0. $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

How to find eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of Sturm-Liouville Problem $$((x^2+1)y’)’+\frac{\lambda }{x^2+1}y=0, y(0)=y(1)=0 $$ In the question hint is given as $$\text{Let}~  x=\tan(t).$$

Now, as we put $x=tan(t)$,  it’s  converted to $$z’’+\lambda cos^2(t)z=0, z(0)=z(\frac{\pi}{4})=0$$ Which is not so easy to solve . Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to change the $'$, since it was $d/dx$, but now you need to find $d/dt$ by the chain rule

Comment: As in the last question, write $y(x)=z(t)$. Everything cancels the same way, as in any other DE of the type $(f(x)^{-1}y'(x))'+\lambda f(x)y(x)=0$, where then $t=F(x)$ with $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: why don't you write $\cos^2(t)$ instead of $1/\sec^2(t)$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi sir I think it is written correct ?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sir $cos^2(t)$ is creating problem.

Comment: No, you are missing an inner derivative in the first term, the common factor $\cos^2t=\frac1{1+\tan^2t}$ can then be split off.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann sorry sir I am unable to get the point . Please help if possible.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$.

Comment: So $\frac{dy}{dt}=(1+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: I think you are saying like this, that next step will be $ z’’(\frac{1}{sec^2(x)})?$ in first term ?

Comment: So that $sec^2(x)$ will cancel from all terms .

Comment: Transformation with $x=\tan(t)$ leads to
$$\cos^2 (t) \left(z''+\lambda  z\right)=0$$
but not
$$z’’+\lambda cos^2(t)z=0$$

Comment: I hope my spelling and formatting changes/corrections are ok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get directly a simplified form
$$
[(1+x^2)D]^2y+\lambda y=0.
$$
The derivative operator can be made into a pure derivative
$$
(1+x^2)D=(1+x^2)\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{d}{d(\arctan x)}
$$
Thus it makes sense to solve the equation first in the variable $t=\arctan x$ or $x=\tan(t)$, where the equation then reduces to $$
z''(t)+\lambda z(t)=0,~~~z(t)=y(x)=y(\tan t)
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is true that

$$ \frac{d}{dx} = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\frac{d}{dt} $$

But your mistake was

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(\left(1+x^2\right)\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right) \neq \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} $$

Instead it is equal to

$$ \frac{1}{1+x^2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} $$

So you end up with

$$ y''(t) + \lambda y(t) = 0 $$